# Google Maps iOS continous spinner for navigation

Tags: ios, google-maps

In the application user has possible to open Google maps with navigation to the stop. When user has enabled location permission in the system dialog, everything works correct - Google Maps is opened, load and show path between selected stop and current user location. The situation changes when user has disabled location permission. In this case Google maps opens but is unable to load path on the maps. It also show endless loading indicator in navigation steps place.

[image]

Recorded movie: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MriakRfRhILNmdv_TvAXDhaz_uMrZag4/view?usp=sharing

Any ideas how to fix this issue, to force Google maps showing navigation path in case of disabled location permission in my app?

For opening google maps we use url:

```
comgooglemaps://?saddr=&center=56.66927193017708,12.864841503952087&directionsmode=walking&daddr=Halmstad+C+(T%C3%A5g)
```

I use Google Maps

pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 4.1.0'

Example of this bug is in the project:

- https://github.com/sayler8182/GoogleMapBugTester

Comment: I have the same issue in my app. Have you found a solution or workaround?

Comment: Actually in my experience, this happens even if the permissions are enabled.  Instead, the spinner behavior takes place if Google Maps isn't already running on the device, whereas everything works fine if the app is already running in the background.

Comment: @Codiak I don't have any solution nor workaround. I raported this issue to Google support, but without any response.

Comment: FYI, I just revisited this bug some 11 months later and can no longer reproduce it.  I had just removed support for Google Maps navigation in my app and just used Apple Maps instead, but now that it seems to have been fixed at some point, I've reinstated the old behavior.